# How do I view the list of commits that haven't been pushed yet?

Tags: git, git-bash

I like documenting minor changes as separate commits and finally use `git interactive --rebase` to combine commits and change commit messages like I deem appropriate.

Is there a way to determine which commits I haven't pushed yet **without manually checking Github** i.e. is there a way to find out from the shell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you do a `git log origin/master..HEAD`, it should show you all the commits that have not been pushed (assuming you are on master, of course).